# designing with linear layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design following design in android using Linear layout
[image]

I had written following code but not working

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />           
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weightSum="2" >
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:text="TextView" android:layout_weight="1" />        
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:text="TextView" />
                    </LinearLayout>                
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" android:hint="TestData"/>
            </LinearLayout>            
</LinearLayout>
```

it gives me output like

[image]

can anyone pointout me.. where is problem???

Comment: whats the output u r getting look like?

Comment: could you pinpoint..what is the problem? what does **but not working** mean?

Comment: @ArchanA Is it compulsory to use LinearLayout?

Comment: @Dipak Keshariya no not compulsary to use linear layout

Comment: @ArchanA If you have any query regarding android you can tell me anytime.

Comment: @Dipak Keshariya ya sure n Thanks alot..

Comment: @ArchanA For contact me you can visit my profile. http://www.blogger.com/profile/13606378981195326665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toptext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="dsggsdggfsgf"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16px"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datetext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="1 dec 2012"
                android:textColor="#cccccc"
                android:textSize="12px"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dsggsdggfsgfwaffgdgafgggfdgfdgsfgfdgdfsgdfdsggsdggfsgfwaffgdgafgggfdgfdgsfgfdgdfsgdfdsggsdggfsgfwaffgdgafgggfdgfdgsfgfdgdfsgdfdsggsdggfsgfwaffgdgafgggfdgfdgsfgfdgdfsgdf"
            android:textColor="#696969"
            android:textSize="12px" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="dfasdfasdfasfasf" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="07 DEc" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dskfhasjkldfhadjklsfhadjklsfhajkldfhadjklsfhajklsfhajklsdfhajklsdfhajklsdfhajkldf" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will work... :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. But it will be better if you use `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="TestData"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can not use this android:layout_alignParentLeft="true", android:layout_alignParentRight="true" properties with LinearLayout.

Comment: Thanks! Copied that from author's layout

Comment: @Dipak Keshariya i can only use this(android:layout_alignParentLeft="true", android:layout_alignParentRight="true") with relative correct??

Comment: Yes, only with `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @Dipak Keshariya your answer is somewhat what i need..but i want textView2's value right side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use relativelayout at first level, like the following:

```
<relativelayout>
     <imageview align to parent top, left, bottom>
     <linearlayout align to parent to, right, right to image view>
          <textview1/>
          <textview2/>
     </linearlayout>
     <textview align to parent bottom, right, righto to image view, below linearlayout>
 </relativelayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="3" 
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" 
                android:layout_weight="2"/>           
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:weightSum="3"
                             android:orientation="horizontal" >
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                    android:text="hfdfhfj" android:layout_weight="2" />        
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="6 Dec 2012" />

                         </LinearLayout>
                         <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                             <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="fkjfkdsnfdsnfkdsn\nmnfkfknfkdf\nfknf" android:hint="TestData"/>
                         </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>                

        </LinearLayout>            
   </LinearLayout>
```

Try this code.it is exactly what you want.